# What is the difference between the alternative and desktop cd images?

Tags: installation, iso

I would like to know what the difference is between these two versions of the same distro.

```
ubuntu-10.10-alternate-i386.iso    
ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso
```

I think that the **alternative CD** is not **Live**,
but is there any more to it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. The alternate CD comes with all the Ubuntu packages (and so can be used as an upgrade package source by simply running `apt-cdrom add`). The desktop CD has all those packages already installed as part of the `squashfs` image, which is convenient for doing new installations, but unusable for doing upgrades with.

Answer (score 11):

The alternate CD installer is not a live CD. You can't use it to try out Ubuntu, test if Ubuntu works or fix a PC/edit partitions without reinstalling.

The alternate CD installer has a command line (curses or similar) installer, whereas the default live CD has a user friendly graphical installer.

The alternate CD can be used to upgrade your Ubuntu version. This is useful for offline computers.

> [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/index.html) you can find information on how to install Ubuntu from the Alternate CD. The Alternate CD provides more advanced installation options than the standard Desktop CD, which is the recommended method of installing Ubuntu. For instructions on how to use the Desktop CD, see the Graphical Install page on the Ubuntu community documentation site.

Answer (score 1):

The **download size** is another difference, which might be important for some users:

I give examples here for Lubuntu (based on Ubuntu) in 2018 because Lubuntu is targeted for older or low-specs devices. Where size might matter even more.

**Desktop**: **1090** MBytes
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-i386.iso

**Alternate**: **715** MBytes
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04-alternate-i386.iso